# Generar mi propia clave primaria en symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Como haría para crear mi propia primary key que no sea el Id incrementable que genera doctrine automáticamente, es decir quiero tener mi propia clave primaria que no se autoincrementable y que symfony no me tome el id como clave primaria.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

En el campo que vayas a usar como clave primaria, tendrías que usar @ORM\Id(), que es lo que indica que va a ser clave.

Ten cuidado, porque cuando otras entidades estén relacionadas con esa,vas a tener que modificar la clave foránea para que referencie al campo clave de la primera entidad.

**Entidad base**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $clave;
```

**Entidad relacionada N:1 con base**

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Base")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="clave")
 * })
 */
private $claveForanea;
```

En este caso, hay que usar JoinColumns, para especificar parámetros extra que te harán falta